# Iptables(mangle table) cannot detect udp packet traffic with restrictions of destination port

Tags: linux, networking, iptables

#### Operating system information.

Linux raspberrypi 4.14.98-v7+ 
or
Linux debian-stretch-1 4.9.0-11-amd64

#### What happened?

I start a service(ss-redir) which can redirect udp traffic

This service open udp 1080 port

I want to redirect all dns query to udp 127.0.0.1:1080 port

#### What did you do?

```
ip route add local default dev lo table 100
ip rule add fwmark 1 lookup 100
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p udp --dport 53 -j TPROXY --on-port 1080 --tproxy-mark 0x01/0x01
nslookup www.google.com
```

#### What did you expect to see?

Several UDP packet have passed through the PREROUTING chain

The exact amount should be shown in the first(pkts) and second(bytes) column

#### What did you see instead?

```
pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 TPROXY     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:53 TPROXY redirect 0.0.0.0:1080 mark 0x1/0x1
```

#### Configuration in detail.

```
root@User:~# cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

this is my service

```
root@User:~# netstat -ntulp 
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1080            0.0.0.0:*                           3771/ss-redir
```

#### What did you do then?

It seems that the DNS query destination port isn't 53, the packets were captured by wireshark indicate that the dport is 53 and the dest ip is 8.8.8.8.

So I added some other rules before that one in  PREROUTING chain:

```
iptables -t mangle -I PREROUTING --prot udp -d myserverip/32 -j RETURN
iptables -t mangle -I PREROUTING --prot udp -d 192.168.128.10/32 -j RETURN
iptables -t mangle -I PREROUTING --prot udp -d 127.0.0.0/24 -j RETURN
```

then run

`nslookup www.google.com`

`iptables -t mangle -L -nv`

The output looks like this:

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 90 packets, 6699 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0   RETURN     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0             myserverip  
    1    29   RETURN     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            127.0.0.0/24        
    0     0   RETURN     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.128.10      
    0     0   TPROXY     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:53 TPROXY redirect 0.0.0.0:1080 mark 0x1/0x1
```

UDP packets still does not pass ss-redir

I don't know what I did wrong.
This question is driving me crazy. Will someone help me?

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Many thanks

Comment: Wrong chain. You want add rules to the `OUTPUT` chain instead if you want them to apply to traffics originated from the host itself.

Comment: Why aren't you using `DNAT` btw?

Comment: Ha,I got that! I really appreciate your help.

Comment: I added the mask in OUTPUT chain,then the udp traffic was redirected to localhost.

Comment: I don't know the exact difference between DNAT and TPROXY.Maybe because DNAT will modifies the IP header or DNAT  is used in TCP traffic.I guess

Comment: In a word, thank you for your help @Tom Yan, otherwise I don't know how long I will be troubled by this problem.

Comment: I just thought `TPROXY` cannot be used in `OUTPUT` (as `iptables-extensions(8)` states that it can only be used from `PREROUTING`). Good that it works. I guess whether you need `TPROXY` or `DNAT` depends on how your "service" works. (The original destination is not entirely lost either with `DNAT`, as it is still tracked by iptables and there's API to retrieve it; for example that's how squid does it when being a transparent proxy, AFAIK.)